# How to make a CRM with Symfony 2.x

Tags: symfony

I want to make a CRM (like vtiger, suger crm)using Symfony 2 how I start it?

1. what kind of areas should I fillow?
2. Where from I stated it?
3. what are the areas I fi

Answer (score 1):

have a look at orocrm.com it's based on symfony2, it may be a good starting point for use or inspiration

Comment: Thnx have u idea about where should I find Architecture of CRM ?

Comment: Why don't just use OROCRM ?

Comment: functions are different it's health care CRM